# Codename One project jar file is not generated

Tags: eclipse, ant, jar, codenameone

I have created a Hello World application in Codename One (I am using Eclipse Mars version).

I can build and run the simulator without a problem. It properly generates .class files under bin directory.

But it does not create .jar file under dist directory.
I think this file is supposed to be generated automatically.

Do I need to check an option in the project properties so that .jar file of the project can be generated under dist directory?

Does this problem signal an incorrect Eclipse (and/or Apache Ant) installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't generate jar files by default only when you send a build as the ant file is used for that.

The jar files generated for a Codename One application aren't very useful as you can't just run them anywhere. You need to send a build to get a native application regardless of the IDE you use.

Comment: Other "Eclipse + Codename One" installations I am using do generate .jar (in dist) automatically without requiring me to send a build?? But there is a specific machine that do not generate this automatically. So I am wondering what is different about that machine.  I use the jar file to run the project from the command line like follows: "java -cp dist\Project.jar;JavaSE.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator
com.mycompany.pkg.MainClass" Is it possible to run the project from command line using the class files in the bin directory instead of using the .jar in the dist directory?

Comment: Why not use the classpath to the classes directory instead of the jar? I'm guessing newer projects don't include the jar in the builders list to speed up the compile on save behavior of Eclipse.